# On a tidally locked moon of a gas giant, would the atmosphere bulge along with the crust?

Tags: moons, gas-giants, tidally-locked, tidal-forces

So I did the math and the crust would bulge 8000 meters due to being tidally locked. On Earth such an elevation would mean the air is extremely thin.

I was wondering if the atmosphere would bulge along with the crust, or if it would remain spherical, thus cutting off some areas from breathable air. Would the bulged area "act" more like a mountain or just another part of the surface? Would the temperature be lower, or winds higher, compared to the non-bulged areas?

Answer (score 4):

The shape of a celestial body is dictated by an equilibrium of forces. I.e. planets are spherical because they are in hidrostatic equilibrium, but due to rotation they are larger at their equator, more so the faster they spin.

On our own Earth we see this with the oceans: gravity is not everywhere 9.81 m/s2, so where the local value is higher, oceans are lower than the average surface, where the local value is lower, oceans are higher.

In the case of a tidally locked moon, anything on the moon would be subjected to the gravity of the other planet, atmosphere included, therefore also the atmosphere would bulge.

Comment: So you are claiming that Jinx, in Larry Niven's known space stories is impossible?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space#Other_planets